# Questions about asymmetric random walk

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, random-walk

Let $X_1, X_2,\dots$ be i.i.d random variables with $\mathbb P(X_1=1)=\mathbb P(X_1=-2)=\frac 1 2.$ I need to consider $S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ with $S_n = 0$.

> What is $\mathbb P\left(\sup\limits_{n\geqslant 0} S_n \geqslant k\right)$ for $k\in\mathbb N$?

I know that $S_n$ is a supermartingale because
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[S_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n] &= S_n + \frac 1 2 \cdot 1 - \frac 1 2\cdot 2\\
&= S_n-\frac 12\\
&\leqslant S_n.
\end{align*}
How can I use Doob's martingale inequality then? Furthermore I know that $$\mathbb P\left(\sup\limits_{n\geqslant 0} S_n \geqslant k\right) = \mathbb P\left(\inf\{n\in\mathbb N|S_n = k\} < \infty\right).$$
Is it useful to consider $X_i$ with $\mathbb P(X_1=1)= \frac 1 3, \mathbb P(X_1=-1)=\frac 2 3$ or $-S_n$? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3352591/expected-hitting-time-of-asymmetric-random-walkhttps://) looks somewhat related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P_k=P(\sup_n S_n\ge k)$, for each $k\ge 0$. On the one hand, it is pretty easy to prove that
$$
\begin{align}
P_k&=\frac12P_{k-1}+\frac12P_{k+2},\qquad (k\ge 1)\tag1
\end{align}
$$
On the other hand, you can prove that
$$
P_k = (P_1)^k,\qquad (k\ge 0)\tag2
$$
This is because you can only move upward in increments of one, so if you reach $k$, you must hit $\ell$ for each $\ell\in \{1,\dots,k-1\}$. Therefore, reaching $k$ starting from $0$ is equivalent to...

- Reaching $1$ starting from $0$, then
- reaching  $2$ starting from $1$, then
- reachinng $3$ starting from $2$, then
- $\vdots$
- reaching $k$ starting from $(k-1)$.

Each bullet point has a probability of $P_1$, since they are all equivalent processes to starting at $0$ and eventually moving to $1$.

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, you get
$$
P_1=\frac12 +\frac12P_1^3 
$$
The possible solutions to $x=\frac12(1+x^3)$ are $x\in \{1,\frac{-1\pm \sqrt5}{2}\}$. The negative solution can obviously be ignored. Furthermore, you can prove that $P_1=1$ is impossible. If $P_1=1$, this would mean the process will move from $0\to 1$ with probability $1$, and then $1\to 2$ with probability $1$, then $2\to 3$, and so on, eventually reaching arbitrarily high values. However, this would contradict the fact that $S_n\to-\infty$ almost surely, which is implied by SLLN.

Therefore, we deduce that $P_1=\frac12(-1+\sqrt 5)$, the inverse of the golden ratio.